# Why does fastmember not seem faster than reflection here?

Tags: .net, fastmember

(this is via a question on twitter, re-asked here with permission)

I'm trying to validate some objects quickly (to test for nulls), and I thought FastMember might be able to help - however, with the tests shown below I am seeing much worse performance. Am I doing something wrong?

```
public class ValidateStuffTests
{
        [Test]
        public void Benchmark_speed()
        {
            var player = CreateValidStuffToTest();
            _stopwatch.Start();
            CharacterActions.IsValid(player);
            _stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(_stopwatch.Elapsed);
            Assert.Less(_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, 10, string.Format("IsValid took {0} mileseconds", _stopwatch.Elapsed));

        }

        [Test]
        public void When_Benchmark_fastMember()
        {
            var player = CreateValidStuffToTest();
            _stopwatch.Start();
            CharacterActions.IsValidFastMember(player);
            _stopwatch.Stop();
            Assert.Less(_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, 10, string.Format("IsValid took {0} mileseconds", _stopwatch.Elapsed));

        }
}

public static class ValidateStuff
    {
        public static bool IsValid<T>(T actions)
        {
            var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (var property in propertyInfos)
            {
                if (property.GetValue(actions, null) == null)                               
                    return false;               
            }
            return true;
        }

        public static bool IsValidFastMember<T>(T actions)
        {
            var typeAccessor = TypeAccessor.Create(typeof(T));

            foreach (var property in typeAccessor.GetMembers())
            {
                if (typeAccessor[actions, property.Name] == null)               
                    return false;               
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem here is that you are including the 1-off cost of meta-programming inside the timing. FastMember incurs some overhead while it processes the types and generates suitable IL, and of course: all of the IL generation layers then need JIT on top of that. So yes, used once : FastMember may appear more expensive. And indeed, you wouldn't *use* something like FastMember if you were only going to do this work once (reflection would be fine). The trick is to do everything once (in both tests) **outside** the timing, so that the first run performance isn't biasing the results. And, in performance, you usually need to run things a lot more than once. Here's my rig:

```
const int CYCLES = 500000;
[Test]
public void Benchmark_speed()
{
    var player = CreateValidStuffToTest();
    ValidateStuff.IsValid(player); // warm up
    var _stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < CYCLES; i++)
    {
        ValidateStuff.IsValid(player);
    }
    _stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(_stopwatch.Elapsed);
    Console.WriteLine("Reflection: {0}ms", _stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

[Test]
public void When_Benchmark_fastMember()
{
    var player = CreateValidStuffToTest();
    ValidateStuff.IsValidFastMember(player); // warm up
    var _stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < CYCLES; i++)
    {
        ValidateStuff.IsValidFastMember(player);
    }
    _stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("FastMember: {0}ms", _stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Which shows fast-member a fair bit faster, but not as much as I would like - 600ms (reflection) vs 200ms (FastMember); quite possibly the 1.0.11 changes biased things too much towards large classes (using 1.0.10 takes only 130ms). I might release a 1.0.12 that uses different strategies for small vs large classes to compensate.

However! In your case, if all you want to test is `null`, I would actually put serious consideration into optimizing that case via IL directly.

For example, the following takes just 45ms for the same test:

```
[Test]
public void When_Benchmark_Metaprogramming()
{
    var player = CreateValidStuffToTest();
    Console.WriteLine(ValidateStuff.IsValidMetaprogramming(player)); // warm up
    var _stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < CYCLES; i++)
    {
        ValidateStuff.IsValidMetaprogramming(player);
    }
    _stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Metaprogramming: {0}ms", _stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

using:

```
public static bool IsValidMetaprogramming<T>(T actions)
{
    return !NullTester<T>.HasNulls(actions);
}
```

and some suitably crazy meta-programming code that does the test for any given `T` all in one place:

```
static class NullTester<T>
{
    public static readonly Func<T, bool> HasNulls;

    static NullTester()
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Exercise for reader: value-type T");

        var props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        var dm = new DynamicMethod("HasNulls", typeof(bool), new[] { typeof(T) });
        var il = dm.GetILGenerator();

        Label next, foundNull;
        foundNull = il.DefineLabel();
        Dictionary<Type, LocalBuilder> locals = new Dictionary<Type, LocalBuilder>();
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            if (!prop.CanRead) continue;
            var getter = prop.GetGetMethod(false);
            if (getter == null) continue;
            if (prop.PropertyType.IsValueType
                && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) == null)
            {   // non-nullable value-type; can never be null
                continue;
            }
            next = il.DefineLabel();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, getter);
            if (prop.PropertyType.IsValueType)
            {
                // have a nullable-value-type on the stack; need
                // to call HasValue, which means we need it as a local
                LocalBuilder local;
                if (!locals.TryGetValue(prop.PropertyType, out local))
                {
                    local = il.DeclareLocal(prop.PropertyType);
                    locals.Add(prop.PropertyType, local);
                }
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, local);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, local);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
                    prop.PropertyType.GetProperty("HasValue").GetGetMethod(false));
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, next);                 
            }
            else
            {
                // is a class; fine if non-zero
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, next);
            }
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Br, foundNull);
            il.MarkLabel(next);
        }
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        il.MarkLabel(foundNull);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        HasNulls = (Func<T, bool>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, bool>));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I m the person that asked this originally. First of thanks for looking into this and taking the time to answer and give an alternative. The thing is, in the scenario I have I don't know the types that will come to be validated before hand really so best I can do is I can cache them as I go, but given the type of application I have this could be a problem, I like your crazy meta programming solution :D. Cheers

Comment: Does FastMember internally cache the member accessor (setter/getter) delegates per every type? If not which class/instance does the IL generation here (that I should cache) ?

Comment: @nawfal yes, it does

Comment: Alright, thank you. That was clear in your example, should have noticed :)